# What does // and :: in the values of environment variables mean?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

On my Linux machine some of the environment variables contain lists of directories. The directories are separated by `:`. But sometimes they are separated by `::`. Is it just a mistake that should be treated as `:` or it means that and empty string is one of the directories (that probably should be interpreted as the current directory).

Most of the directories specified in the environment variables have this format:

```
/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

However, some of them have this format:

```
/aaa/bbb//ccc
```

Note double slash between `bbb` and `ccc`. Is it just a mistake that is interpreted as a single slash or it has a special meaning?

Answer (score 5):

The double-colon (`::`) does indeed mean the current directory. The [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html) describes `PATH` as:

> A colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for
>   commands. A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH
>   indicates the current directory. A null directory name may appear as
>   two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon.

But personally, I think it's better to explicitly specify the current directory (e.g., `/foo/bar:.`) for clarity.

As for the slashes, any number of adjacent slashes is treated as a single slash.

Answer (score 1):

multiple '/' separators are ignored:

```
$ cd .////somedir
```

is equivalent to

```
$ cd somedir
```

As for the extra separators in your PATH, a little experimentation suggests that they are also ignored.

At least, this:

```
/home/jon.kiparsky:2040 $ echo $PATH
/home/jon.kiparsky/bin::::::/home/jon.kiparsky/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

did not break my path! :)